# Referencing CLR Class library in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, clr, class-library

I have a Silverlight project and a C# CLR class library project. The problem is i cannot add a reference of the class library to the Silverlight project (because it is not a silverlight assembly). Is there any way i can make use of the class library in my silverlight application? 
   Is there a way to compile the Class library into a silverlight assembly or can i add an intermediate project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are targeting atleast Silverlight 4 make your class library a [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Silverlight project, and add file links to your original project. If there are features in .NET4 that aren't available in Silverlight, you can test it using #if SILVERLIGHT and comment it out.